# How to mediaplayer with media session?

Tags: java, android

HEllo friend i am new in android creating mp3 player my mp3 works fine they have play pause next and pervious control i want to do same thing using service how implement this thing in service for control media player here my services class  can you tell me how can play and pause music using service?
i take this code from this site https://www.binpress.com/android-media-style-notifications-media-session-controls/

```
package music.playerforandroid;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.Rating;
import android.media.session.MediaController;
import android.media.session.MediaSession;
import android.media.session.MediaSessionManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MediaPlayerService extends Service {

    public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "action_play";
    public static final String ACTION_PAUSE = "action_pause";
    public static final String ACTION_REWIND = "action_rewind";
    public static final String ACTION_FAST_FORWARD = "action_fast_foward";
    public static final String ACTION_NEXT = "action_next";
    public static final String ACTION_PREVIOUS = "action_previous";
    public static final String ACTION_STOP = "action_stop";

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private MediaSessionManager mManager;
    private MediaSession mSession;
    private MediaController mController;

    MainActivity mainActivity=new MainActivity();


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void handleIntent( Intent intent ) {
        if( intent == null || intent.getAction() == null )
            return;

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if( action.equalsIgnoreCase( ACTION_PLAY ) ) {

            mController.getTransportControls().play();
        }


        else if( action.equalsIgnoreCase( ACTION_PAUSE ) ) {


                 mController.getTransportControls().pause();

        }


        else if( action.equalsIgnoreCase( ACTION_FAST_FORWARD ) ) {
            mController.getTransportControls().fastForward();
        } else if( action.equalsIgnoreCase( ACTION_REWIND ) ) {
            mController.getTransportControls().rewind();
        } else if( action.equalsIgnoreCase( ACTION_PREVIOUS ) ) {
            mController.getTransportControls().skipToPrevious();
        } else if( action.equalsIgnoreCase( ACTION_NEXT ) ) {
            mController.getTransportControls().skipToNext();
        } else if( action.equalsIgnoreCase( ACTION_STOP ) ) {
            mController.getTransportControls().stop();
        }
    }

    private Notification.Action generateAction( int icon, String title, String intentAction ) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class );
        intent.setAction( intentAction );
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);
        return new Notification.Action.Builder( icon, title, pendingIntent ).build();
    }

    private void buildNotification( Notification.Action action ) {
        Notification.MediaStyle style = new Notification.MediaStyle();

        Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class );
        intent.setAction( ACTION_STOP );
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder( this )
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_music)
                .setContentTitle( "Media Title" )
                .setContentText( "Media Artist" )
                .setDeleteIntent( pendingIntent )
                .setStyle(style);

        builder.addAction( generateAction( android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, "Previous", ACTION_PREVIOUS ) );
        builder.addAction( generateAction( android.R.drawable.ic_media_rew, "Rewind", ACTION_REWIND ) );
        builder.addAction( action );
        builder.addAction( generateAction( android.R.drawable.ic_media_ff, "Fast Foward", ACTION_FAST_FORWARD ) );
        builder.addAction( generateAction( android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "Next", ACTION_NEXT ) );
        style.setShowActionsInCompactView(0,1,2,3,4);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
        notificationManager.notify( 1, builder.build() );
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if( mManager == null ) {
            initMediaSessions();
        }

        handleIntent( intent );
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void initMediaSessions() {
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        mSession = new MediaSession(getApplicationContext(), "simple player session");
        mController =new MediaController(getApplicationContext(), mSession.getSessionToken());

        mSession.setCallback(new MediaSession.Callback(){
                                 @Override
                                 public void onPlay() {
                                     super.onPlay();
                                     Log.e( "MediaPlayerService", "onPlay");
                                     buildNotification( generateAction( android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Pause", ACTION_PAUSE ) );


                                 }

                                 @Override
                                 public void onPause() {
                                     super.onPause();
                                     Log.e( "MediaPlayerService", "onPause");




                                     buildNotification(generateAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play, "Play", ACTION_PLAY));

                                 }

                                 @Override
                                 public void onSkipToNext() {
                                     super.onSkipToNext();
                                     Log.e( "MediaPlayerService", "onSkipToNext");
                                     //Change media here
                                     buildNotification( generateAction( android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Pause", ACTION_PAUSE ) );
                                 }

                                 @Override
                                 public void onSkipToPrevious() {
                                     super.onSkipToPrevious();
                                     Log.e( "MediaPlayerService", "onSkipToPrevious");
                                     //Change media here
                                     buildNotification( generateAction( android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Pause", ACTION_PAUSE ) );
                                 }

                                 @Override
                                 public void onFastForward() {
                                     super.onFastForward();
                                     Log.e( "MediaPlayerService", "onFastForward");
                                     //Manipulate current media here
                                 }

                                 @Override
                                 public void onRewind() {
                                     super.onRewind();
                                     Log.e( "MediaPlayerService", "onRewind");
                                     //Manipulate current media here
                                 }

                                 @Override
                                 public void onStop() {
                                     super.onStop();
                                     Log.e( "MediaPlayerService", "onStop");
                                     //Stop media player here
                                     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                     notificationManager.cancel( 1 );
                                     Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class );
                                     stopService( intent );
                                 }

                                 @Override
                                 public void onSeekTo(long pos) {
                                     super.onSeekTo(pos);
                                 }

                                 @Override
                                 public void onSetRating(Rating rating) {
                                     super.onSetRating(rating);
                                 }
                             }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        mSession.release();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

}
```